# cookie checkbox glitch

Tags: php

When I tick check box (cookie) and press log in
it didn't header to member page. It header to index page (current page).

but when I tick the check box (cookie) and press log again
it header to member page

anyone can help me where is the problem?

```
<?PHP
session_start();

function loggedin(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['log_email']) || isset($_COOKIE['log_email'])){
    $loggedin=TRUE;
    return $loggedin;   
    }
}

$log_email="";

if(loggedin()){
header("Location:member.php");}

if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $log_email=strtolower($_POST['log_email']);
    $log_password=$_POST['log_password'];

    if(isset($_POST['cookie'])){
    $cookie=$_POST['cookie'];
    }


    if($log_email && $log_password){
        $connect=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        $database=mysql_select_db("phplogin", $connect);

        $SQL=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$log_email'");
        $numrows=mysql_num_rows($SQL);

        if($numrows!=0){
            while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($SQL)){
                $db_email=$result['email'];
                $db_password=$result['password'];
                $db_firstname=$result['firstname'];
                $db_lastname=$result['lastname'];
            }

            if($log_email==$db_email && md5($log_password)==$db_password){      
                    if($cookie){
                        setcookie("log_email", $log_email, time()+7200);
                    }
                    else{
                    $_SESSION['log_email']=$log_email;
                    header("location:member.php");
                    exit();
                    }
            }
            else{echo"wrong username or password";}
        }
        else{echo "Can't find the user";}
    }
    else{echo "Please enter email or password";}
}


?>




<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="search"></div>
    <div id="top_search"></div>


    <div id="login">
        <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><lable id="td_1">Email</lable></td>
                <td><lable id="td_1">Password</lable></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="log_email" value="<?PHP echo $log_email; ?>" maxlength="50"/></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="log_password" maxlength="25" /></td>
                <td><input id="log_btn" type="submit" name="login" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div id="td_2"><input type="checkbox" name="cookie"/>Remember me</div></td>
                <td><div id=td_2><a href="forgot_password.php">Forgot your password?</div></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </div>   

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't print HTML or other output before sending headers.

Answer (score 1):

You start this page with `<html>` and some more data before you open with `<?php`. Header will only work when there is no output to the browser yet, so this wont work (unless there is some sort of output buffering active on the page, before the code you show.)

Just start with `<?php` and move the `<html>` and other tags (including the newlines) to after the php code to check for login.

And then instead of directly outputing the error messages with `echo`, store them in a var like `$error = "wrong username or password";` and then print it later on in the HTML code with `<?php echo $error; ?>`

```
    <?PHP
    session_start();

    function loggedin(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['log_email']) || isset($_COOKIE['log_email'])){
        $loggedin=TRUE;
        return $loggedin;   
        }
    }

    $log_email="";
    $error = "";

    if(loggedin()){
    header("Location:member.php");}

    if(isset($_POST['login'])){

        $log_email=strtolower($_POST['log_email']);
        $log_password=$_POST['log_password'];

        if(isset($_POST['cookie'])){
        $cookie=$_POST['cookie'];
        }


        if($log_email && $log_password){
            $connect=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
            $database=mysql_select_db("phplogin", $connect);

            $SQL=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$log_email'");
            $numrows=mysql_num_rows($SQL);

            if($numrows!=0){
                while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($SQL)){
                    $db_email=$result['email'];
                    $db_password=$result['password'];
                    $db_firstname=$result['firstname'];
                    $db_lastname=$result['lastname'];
                }

                if($log_email==$db_email && md5($log_password)==$db_password){      
                        if($cookie){
                            setcookie("log_email", $log_email, time()+7200);
                            header("location:member.php");
                        }
                        else{
                        $_SESSION['log_email']=$log_email;
                        header("location:member.php");
                        exit();
                        }
                }
                else{$error = "wrong username or password";}
            }
            else{$error = "Can't find the user";}
        }
        else{$error = "Please enter email or password";}
    }


    ?>


    <html>
    <link href="CSS/login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="search"></div>
        <div id="top_search"></div>


        <div id="login">



            <?php
            if (strlen($error)>0)
              echo $error;
            ?>


            <form action="index.php" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><lable id="td_1">Email</lable></td>
                    <td><lable id="td_1">Password</lable></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="log_email" value="<?PHP echo $log_email; ?>" maxlength="50"/></td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="log_password" maxlength="25" /></td>
                    <td><input id="log_btn" type="submit" name="login" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><div id="td_2"><input type="checkbox" name="cookie"/>Remember me</div></td>
                    <td><div id=td_2><a href="forgot_password.php">Forgot your password?</div></a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
        </div>   

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I add header under setcookie and it solve the problem

setcookie("log_email", $log_email, time()+7200);
header("location:member.php");